# Protractor Configuration for path to binary

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to add the equivalent of the "binary" chrome options for an existing project running protractor tests for a specific path to the Chrome browser. The configuration currently in place is as follows (buildConf being the build configuration):

```
    protractorConfig.capabilities.chromeOptions =
      setChromeOptions([
        '--no-sandbox', 
        '--disable-infobars=true',
        '--allow-insecure-localhost', 
        '--ignore-certificate-errors', 
        '--window-size=1280,1024', 
      ], buildConf);
```

The option I am trying to add is the path to the binary. I can successfully do it using the following syntax.

```
  protractorConfig.capabilities = {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions' : {
      'binary': 'C:\Projects\CustomBrowser\chrome.exe',
      'debuggerAddress': '127.0.0.1:8088'
    }
  };
```

I could not find any equivalent for the 'binary' parameter as a flag in this exhaustive list.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

My question is: can anyone tell me what the equivalent --flag is for the 'binary' parameter? I tried:

```
--binary='C:\Projects\CustomBrowser\chrome.exe'
--path-to-binary: 'C:\Projects\CustomBrowser\chrome.exe'
```

Thank you. Let me know if I am not explaining the issue properly or need more details.

Comment: Just getting some clarification, flag for the Chrome binary in the Protractor CLI? I don't think we have one.

Comment: That's correct. Does it mean that I have to change the way the configuration is set from using "setChromeOptions" to the "ChromeOptions" object? Thank you for the feedback.